# How should I use i18n translate in this situation?(Translate text with variables)

Tags: angular, internationalization, ngx-translate, angular-i18n

I'm working with Angular 7. I need to translate texts with variables.
Let's say I want to translate it to German. The words(variables) needs to change positions because of the language properties.

Example:

> EN: Logged in as Robert.
>
> DE: Als Robert angemeldet.

Can't decide how can i deal with the situation properly.
Can somebody answer for me with an easy example? Thank you for your feedback.

Usually, I'm dealing with translations like this:

In component:

> {{'Dashboard' | translate}}

i18n DE.json:

> "Dashboard": "Armaturenbrett"

I need to translate strings like these:

> description: "{{example.asd@qwe.com}} user uploads {{fileType}}{{fileName}} for {{company}} via {{deviceType}}."
>
> summary: "days: {{daysNumber}}; distance: {{distanceCount}}"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood your question properly.
Is this what you intended?

En.json:

```
"description" : "{{email}} user uploads {{fileType}}{{fileName}} for {{company}} via {{deviceType}}"
```

Ko.json:

```
"description" : "{{email}} 사용자가 {{deviceType}}을 통해 {{company}}에 대한 {{fileType}} {{fileName}}을 업로드합니다"
```

Html:

```
<span>{{'description' | translate : {email : 'example@example.com', deviceType: 'exampleDevice', company: 'exampleCompany', fileType: '.exe', fileName: 'exampleName' } }}</span>
```

Comment: Made some little changes but it's perfect. Exactly what i was looking for. Thank you for sharing it with me and of course thank you for your time.